# XScope program for Linux/XFree or X.Org

Tags: linux, utilities

Where can I find an XScope program, debugger/tracer of xlib calls, for Linux with XFree/X.Org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is available at http://ftp.x.org/pub/individual/app/

I don't see a lot of binary packages. 
Building it from source is not difficult.  What distribution are you using?

Comment: I use LFS. Does XScope needs a sources/headers from very recent X.org?

Comment: No.  It's been around since X11R5.